# How to avoid distortion by changing the position of a subView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a `NSViewController` which I assigned to my main application with code :

```
self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
```

I also set the autosizing attributes, so that if I change the size of the main window, the subview will change accordingly.

So far so good. The problem is that the subview does not hook up to the top of the main window, so I added this line :

```
self.masterViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,120, self.masterViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.masterViewController.view.frame.size.height);
```

Now, with this line, I see the actual problem. The drawing of the subview gets distorted.

The issue can been seen here :[image]

Thanks for the help.

-mcb